# How do use the define_webjump in conkeror

Tags: browser

I have started to use [conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) yesterday and so far I like it it has a good documentation apart from one wierd thing. I want to add [duck duck go](http://duckduckgo.com) to my [webjump](http://conkeror.org/Webjumps) options.

I have found that I *need* to use the syntax

```
    define_webjump(name,target)
```

(I'm not sure that this is the right name but it is symilar). What I couldn't find is *where* should I use that command.

Does any of you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It said in the *rc file*, that is located in

```
    $HOME/.conkerorrc
```

as the man page says.